# Deleting more than one record from a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have code behind a button that deletes a record from a subform. The code works when I first open the parent form. If I select another record to delete, it does not work again. I must close the form and reopen, and again it only works one time.

I tried commenting out all other code in other procedures to isolate the problem (such as Form_Open), but have failed to find what is causing the problem.

The code:

```
Dim LResponse As Integer
    
LResponse = MsgBox("Do you wish to Delete this local Vendor?", vbYesNo, "Delete Local Vendor")

If LResponse = vbYes Then
   
    Me.VendorPrograms_subform.Form.Recordset.Delete
    Me.VendorPrograms_subform.Form.Recordset.MoveNext
        
Else
   DoCmd.CancelEvent
End If
```

I also tried SQL:

```
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "DELETE * FROM VendorPrograms WHERE VendorId# = " & "Me!VENDOR#"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
Me!VendorPrograms_subform.Requery
```

This code does not throw an error, but the record is not deleted.

Comment: Are you sure record is deleted from table? Deleting Recordset should not delete a record, it should just disassociate form from data. If button is on main form then suggest you run a DELETE sql action then requery subform. If you delete a vendor are there dependent records that must also be deleted?

Comment: Yes, the record is deleted the first time from the subform table. There are not other dependent records that need to be deleted. I have tried a sql delete action and had problems with it as well. I am going to restore that code to see if that shines a light on the problem. Thank you for your help. I'll right back with what I find happens with the SQL.

Comment: I have never even seen Recordset.Delete. Edit question to show other attempted code and explain the error - what message.

Comment: So the SQL code is: 

    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim MyID As String
    
    MyID = Me![VendorId#]
    
    sSQL = "DELETE * FROM VendorPrograms WHERE [VendorId#] = " & MyID
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
    Me!VendorPrograms_subform.Requery

This almost works, It however opens a Parameter Query window and if I enter the ID# it will actually delete that subrecord. I of course don't want it to ask for the ID# I want it to get it from the form.

Comment: sounds like this might be a me.requery issue

Comment: So, I have gone back to the first code since it at least deletes the first time. It just will not work again until I close and reopen the form. Doug, the me.requery doesn't help. 

I also tried simplifying things by deleting all relationships so that there is just a 1 to 1 relationship between the VENDORDATA table and the VendorPrograms table. That didn't help. I also tried deleting all other subforms and sub-subforms. That didn't help either. I tried deleting all other code. That didn't help. I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being the queries under the form and subform. I had to simplify both to include just the main-table for the main-form and the sub-table for the subform.

In the past, if I recall correctly, I could not do data-entry in forms if the query included more than one table. This has changed and now multiple tables in queries will work for data-entry, however it appears that deleting records off of subforms is partially not allowed (I was able to delete one record after opening the form but further deletions do not work) if multiple tables are used in queries.

Here is the code that worked:

```vb
Dim LResponse As Integer
    
LResponse = MsgBox("Do you wish to Delete this local Vendor?", vbYesNo, "Delete Local Vendor")

If LResponse = vbYes Then
        
    Me![VendorPrograms subform1].Form![VendorId#].SetFocus
    Me.[VendorPrograms subform1].Form.Recordset.Delete
    Me.[VendorPrograms subform1].Form.Recordset.MoveNext
    Me.Requery
            
Else
   DoCmd.CancelEvent
End If
```